How can I set parameters inside clouser
I have a function that gets a parameter callId
I checked here and in the first log I get the result "Initializing calendar with ID: 1"
But for the second log I can't get the ID "Select calendar ID:"
How can I send the ID in the clouser selection?
    function updateCalendar(events, calId) {
        console.log('calendar ID inside func updateCalendar', calId);
        const csrftoken = document.getElementById('csrf-token').value;
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var eventsData = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('events-data').textContent);
    
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            events: eventsData,
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true,
            select: createSelectHandler(calId, csrftoken), 


  function createSelectHandler(calId, csrftoken) {
        return function(start, end, allDay) {
            console.log('calendar ID inside func createSelectHandler', calId);


I want to get a reuslt like this
Initializing calendar with ID: 1 Select event triggered calendarId: 1
here is my updeted screenshot for log FILE https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AsLpHekRb5zUF5WzktMssgNzcMNQr11p/view?usp=sharing

function updateCalendar(events, calId) {
console.log('calendar ID inside func updateCalendar', calId);
...
….
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
header: {
left: 'prev,next today',
center: 'title',
right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
},
events: eventsData,
selectable: true,
selectHelper: true,
editable: true,
eventLimit: true,
select: createSelectHandler(calId, csrftoken),

I'm not sure what the problem is? Your code works ok as far as I can see - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/KKjMRmZ?editable=true&editors=001 . Both console.log commands are fired (the second one fires only when you select something on the calendar, of course), and both contain the calendar ID correctly.

Obviously I had to make one or two additions to your incomplete code in order to make the demo runnable. Perhaps you can edit your question to form a [mre] of your issue, where the code you provide would actually make the stated problem occur?  Then we can help you more easily. See also [ask]. Thanks
